# routes for sending multiple custom parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am using `AngularJS` and for some reason I send data through some url `root_app/tasks?param1=$param1&param2=$param2`

I wrote this in my `route.rb` file

```
  resources :tasks, :defaults => {:format => "json"}
  match "tasks/param1=:param1&param2=:param2" => "tasks#update", via: :put
  match "tasks/param1=:param1&param2=:param2" => "tasks#destroy", via: :delete
```

but when I send my data through `AngularJS` I get this message

```
DELETE http://localhost:3000/tasks?param1=1&param2=0 404 (Not Found)
```

Why is it so ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you dont need to match the params in url just write

```
match "/tasks" => "tasks#destroy", via: :delete
```

Comment: could you explain why `resources :tasks` is not sufficient ?

Comment: yes sure through resources the url should be /tasks/:id but your url is not in that pattern

Answer (score 1):

This is because rails ignores the "parameters" portion of the URL string (anything after the `?`) when determining the route. Only the path (everything up to the `?`) is considered.

However, everything in the URL parameters will be in the controller's `params` hash - that's where you want to do your branching. AKA, you'll have `params[:param1]` and `params[:param2]` when in your controller action if you simply `match "tasks" => "tasks#destroy", via: :delete`

If you want to do this with routing, instead of `http://localhost:3000/tasks?param1=1&param2=0` do `http://localhost:3000/tasks/param1/1/param2/0` and use the route `match "tasks/param1/:param1/param2/:param2"`.